# I am stuck on account linking for my custom Alexa skill

Tags: oauth, alexa-skills-kit

Currently, I am working on linking my Alexa skill with my website. I'm stuck. I've followed YouTube tutorials and looked at the documentation. I basically want users to click on the account linking button, be taken to a login page and then have that authorize the users with their own private data. Do I need to create a oauth server? Is there anybody I can talk to who has already done something like this? I created a html page to log users in using an api call but I haven't gotten any further. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two questions that you asked here. Addressing them consecutively:

1. Do you need to an OAuth server for account linking? --> Yes. You either create your own authorization server which uses OAuth2.0 or you can rent it from providers. There are various OAuth server providers like auth0, okta etc.
2. If you have created an html page for login, then it needs to connect with your auth server in the backend and you need an API to do that as well as connect with the LWA server to complete account linking with Alexa.

The auth server will basically generate an auth code upon authenticating the user and subsequently it will generate an access token. Both these URLs must be mentioned in the Amazon Alexa developer console.
Then you need to make the calls to LWA to complete authentication with Amazon. This will generate an LWA auth code and subsequently an access token.
This LWA access token along with user auth code generated by your auth server will be used to enable the skill from your website.

Feel free to contact me if you have more queries! Good luck.

Comment: Can you please help me out on this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71427697/alexa-out-of-session-skill-messaging-api