# Alexa Out -of- session - Skill Messaging API

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I’m trying to create an Alexa capability that creates reminders without user voice invocation. To achieve this Alexa suggested to use “Out of session” interaction event i.e **Skill Messaging API** ([https://api.amazonalexa.com/v1/skillmessages/users/{userId}](https://api.amazonalexa.com/v1/skillmessages/users/%7BuserId%7D)), as you can see in the API we need to pass the user Id, In order to get the user Id Alexa suggest to do first account-linking, once linking is done we’ll get the user profile access including userId. Now, after hitting the Skill Messaging API with received userId, it returns
{type:”not_found”, a message ”invalid user Id”}.

Not sure where am I going wrong. Has anyone phase the same problem.

Comment: I am looking for exactly the same usecase. Did you figure out anything on this yet? @sachin gupta

Answer (score 0):

In the request shown next, set HOST to one of the following, depending on the user's region: api.amazonalexa.com, api.eu.amazonalexa.com, or api.fe.amazonalexa.com